# Assigning id to validation message

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am trying to assign id to span where validation message is dynamically shown. Am I doing some thing wrong?

```
 <div>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title,new{id="prjTitle"})</div>
```

It throws Argument type is not assignable to parameter string

Answer (score 3):

just use the correct overload:

```
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.YourProperty, "", new { @class = "a-class-if-you-want-one", id = "yourId" })
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no overload that takes only the linq expression and an html attributes object.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationmessagefor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) there is an overload that takes a linq expression, an errormessage (string) AND an html attributes object, like this:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title,"entry invalid",new{id="prjTitle"})
```

Comment: It gets id to parent span and not to error message span, if I try that way. Below is html rendered after adding id as above.

<span class="field-validation-error" id="prjTitle" data-valmsg-for="Title" data-valmsg-replace="true"><span for="Title">Enter Project Title</span></span>

Comment: I guess all that's left then is to write a custom validationmessagefor, like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8381685/1783240

Answer (score 1):

```
public static MvcHtmlString IDValidationMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string id)
    {
        var validationString = Regex.Replace(htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(expression).ToString(), @"^data-valmsg-for=""*\""$", String.Format("data-valmsg-for=\"{0}\"", id));

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(validationString);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you provide some more information how this code answers the question?