# Way to change rendered validation code in MVC4 and Unobtrusive

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

I am developing an application using MVC4 and handling the clienside validation using jquery.validate.unobtrusive.
I am simply using model validation and the following

```
            <label for="fname">Name</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { id = "Name", @maxlength = "16", aria_describedby = "validationName" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, string.Empty, new { id = "validationName" })
```

When I run the code, it renders the validation message with  tags like

```
<span id="validationName" class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Name">
<span class="" for="fname" generated="true">Your name is required.</span>
```

For the CSS purpose, I need to change the span id="validationName" to
p id="validationName"
I think the span tag is coming from framework or something since I can't find span tag anywhere in my code beside the validation js file.
I see "options:errorClass:"input-validation-error",errorElement:"span"" in unobtrusive.js file but changing that span to p changes the second span class="" to p class="" without effecting the first span.

The reason I am looking for p tags is that span tags are best for inline styles; p tags style error message blocks as “block-level elements” which drops them down a line rather than making them wrap. Also, p tags would read describe error messages as “paragraphs” rather than hanging text with no meaning

Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to customize Html.ValidationMessageFor in ASP MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380988/how-to-customize-html-validationmessagefor-in-asp-mvc)

Comment: The Html.ValidationMessageFor helper always returns a span (if there is a message to render, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721293(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: style the span tag as you desire.  add display: block, add a width, and it will be a block element that wraps

Comment: use the class='field-validation-error' and style it as a paragraph